# meteor iron-router session.get doesn't work

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to implement this route:

```
  @route "buildingSpaceTenant",
    path: "/buildings/:_building_id/spaces/:_space_id/tenants/:_id/communications"
    template: "tenant"
    yieldTemplates: {
      Session.get("current_tenant_subtemplate"): {to: "subTemplate"}
    }
```

but apparently I can't use the session object this way.

```
<runJavaScript-30>:148:11: client/routes/tenantsRoute.coffee:44: unexpected . (compiling client/routes/tenantsRoute.coffee) (at handler)
```

What's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variable names as keys in an object literal. If `yieldTemplates` can accept a function (I don't think it can), you could try something like:

```coffee
@route 'buildingSpaceTenant',
  path: '/buildings/:_building_id/spaces/:_space_id/tenants/:_id/communications'
  template: 'tenant'
  yieldTemplates: ->
    templateName = Session.get 'current_tenant_subtemplate'
    obj = {}
    obj[templateName] = to: 'subTemplate'
    obj
```

I had a look at the example from [this issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/523) which implies that you could try overriding `action` to achieve the same end result.

```coffee
@route 'buildingSpaceTenant',
  path: '/buildings/:_building_id/spaces/:_space_id/tenants/:_id/communications'
  template: 'tenant'
  action: ->
    if @ready()
      @render()
      templateName = Session.get 'current_tenant_subtemplate'
      @render templateName, to: 'subTemplate'
    else
      @render 'loading'
```

Give those ideas a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I confirm that, for the moment, you can't associate a function to yieldtemplate. But your workaround does the job. Thanks!